# Retrieving data from Firebase Realtime Database from React-redux app

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

I am trying to query data from my Firebase realtime database based on the child value matchID.

Below is the JSON export of my matchPredictions table with only one entry in it.

```
{
  "-LP0aVMsmqfdHj7yfPnK" : {
    "matchID" : "-LP0LKl_nR4VQf6Gxwz8",
    "matchKickoff" : "2019-01-12T12:00",
    "teamAName" : "Germany",
    "teamAScore" : "2",
    "teamBName" : "Denmark",
    "teamBScore" : "3",
    "userId" : "RZVbxcIB1SWxj0ohgJDqkEU9ia13"
  }
}
```

I have the following function which gets called ..

```
export const fetchPredictionsForCompletedMatch = (match, token) => {
    console.log("Match is " +match);
    console.log("matchPredictionsFBRef is " + matchPredictionsFBRef);
    const retrievePreds = matchPredictionsFBRef.orderByChild("matchID").equalTo(match).on("value",
        function(snapshot){
        console.log("Snapshot here is "+ snapshot);
    });
    return dispatch => {
        retrievePreds.then(
            response => dispatch(addMatchResultSuccess(match))
        )
            .catch(
                err => dispatch(addMatchResultFail(err))
            )
    }
}
```

The value for match is -LP0LKl_nR4VQf6Gxwz8 as expected and matchPredictionsFBRef is https://projectOne.firebaseio.com/matchPredictions, 
which is the table I am trying to query.

When this runs the error "The error is TypeError: retrievePreds.then is not a function" is thrown and snapshot is not printed to the console.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase's `on()` method can give results multiple times. Since a promise can only resolve once, the `on()` method can't return a promise.

If you only want to get a result once, use Firebase's `once()` method instead of `on()`:

```
const retrievePreds = matchPredictionsFBRef.orderByChild("matchID").equalTo(match).once("value",
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you call the function before chaining then.

retrievePreds().then()

Comment: If I do retrievePreds().then( ... then it  does seem to call function but my console output prints ..."Snapshot here is undefined".

Comment: can you reproduce in codesandbox so I can further help you, need to log a couple things

Comment: Hi. I'll give it a go. I'll have a play around on there first, it's not something I have used much.